# Excel Date difference without weekend days

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, weekday

Last time I posted a quite vague story about a date difference challenge which I haven't solved yet. I will try to elaborate since I have tried everything in my power and the problem still isn't fixed.

I currently have three columns.

- Column 1 (`F`)

  - the date a car starts its repairs (format DayOfWeek-DD-MM-YYYY)
- Column 2 (`G`)

  - the number of days in which the car is repaired (service level agreement [SLA]; the standard is 10 days)
- Column 3 (`H`)

  - the output, which is the date the car should be finished. So the number of days after the startdate*

<sup>*Th thing which makes this case difficult is that *only weekdays* are included.</sup>

**So, for example:**

If a car ***starts repairs*** on **Monday 1<sup>st</sup> of August**, the ***finish date*** is **Tuesday the 14<sup>th</sup> of August**.

I tried to solve this with the following formula:

`=IF(WEEKDAY(F218)=2;(F218+11);`

  `IF(WEEKDAY(F218)=3;F218+12;`

 
  `IF(WEEKDAY(F218)=4;F218+13;`

 
  `IF(WEEKDAY(F218)=5;F218+14;`

  `IF(WEEKDAY(F218)=6;F218+15)))))`

**In other words:**

*If startdate = Monday then startdate + 11, 


if startdate = Tuesday then startdate + 12, etc.*

This works, **but** I have 300+ rows and dragging this function down doesn't change the cell references.

I know about the `NETWORKDAYS` and `WEEKDAY` functions, but I encounter problems with any Monday where only **1** weekend passes and other days where **2** weekends pass.

Comment: Are you sure auto-calc is on?  Try F9 to manually recalc and let me know if it still doesn't "drop down"

Comment: So `=WORKDAY(start_date,days,holidays)` wouldn't work?

Comment: This sounds exactly what the `WORKDAY` function is designed to do, although you might have to subtract 1 from the number of days

Comment: @Hambone, f9 does work. However, this function might not be the best solution to the problem right? For instance, if the SLA changes, the whole formula needs to be adapted.
@JvdV & @Ron Rosenfeld, This works perfect, thanks! With the workday function, I ended up with a day to much so i finally used `=WORKDAY(A1-1;B1)`.
Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: @joopert That implies that a job taking one (1) day would start and end on the same day.  So if that is what you expect, then your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

#### *First of all, I am assuming that your first day - whatever day that may be - is considered day one (1). So in my scenario, if a SLA states 2 days to complete a repair and the* start date *is a* Monday*, I'm assuming the repair should be completed by* Tuesday*.*

My assumption is based off this comment by @RonRosenfeld:

> *...although you might have to subtract 1 from the number of days*

---

With all that being said, try this formula in your cell instead:

 **<sup>*NOTE: You may need to change things like commas and semi-colons to adjust for your region.*</sup>**

`=WORKDAY($F2,$G2-1)+LOOKUP(WEEKDAY(WORKDAY($F2,$G2-1),16),{1;2;3},{2;1;0})`

**What it does:**

- `WORKDAY($F2,$G2-1)`

  - First we want to find out exactly what day the repairs *should* be completed by if weekend days (Saturday and Sunday) were included. This part of the formula will simply give us a place to start.
  - `$F2` is your repair start date
  - `$G2` is the number of days a repair is supposed to take (you may need to add a column for this, because, as you stated, the SLA may change and you need the formula to be easily adjusted)
- `WEEKDAY(WORKDAY($F2,$G2-1),16)`

  - The `WORKDAY` function from above is wrapped inside a `WEEKDAY` function. This `WEEKDAY` function is written to account for each day of a week to be assigned numbers. The `[return_type]` parameter of 16 tells Excel to label them as *"Numbers 1 (Saturday) through 7 (Friday)"*. We chose `16` so that our `LOOKUP` function is easier to write. This part of the formula only returns a one-digit number, which in turn will be used to figure out what day of the week we *actually* want when excluding weekends.
- `LOOKUP(WEEKDAY(WORKDAY($F2,$G2-1),16),{1;2;3},{2;1;0})`

  - We finish the formula by adding the result from a `LOOKUP` function using the first form of the function: 
    `LOOKUP(lookup_value,lookup_vector,[result_vector])`
  - We found our `lookup_value` in the previous bullet point using the `WEEKDAY` function. Now we want Excel to use the `lookup_vector` - `{1;2;3}` in our formula - to find the correct value to add to the first part of our formula (which is found using the `[result_vector]` - `{2;1;0}` in our formula).
  - The `lookup_vector` only has three values: 1, 2, and 3.
  - 1 signals Saturday
  - 2 signals Sunday
  - 3 signals all other days
- Think of the `lookup_vector` and `[result_vector]` as forming a matrix/table from which our value is found:

  - 1   2
  - 2   1
  - 3   0
- If our number of repair days pushes us to:

  - a Saturday (1), the formula adds 2.
  - a Sunday (2), the formula adds 1.
  - any *weekday*, the formula adds 0 (since weekdays are acceptable).

---

Hopefully all of this makes sense. Best of luck to you!